# What is a fast, bulk upload, media management system I can install on my website?

Tags: php, html, image, video

Constantly I am annoyed with the slow speeds of Facebook, Youtube and the like when uploading media. Recently, I have also become annoyed at how these organizations store my data and use it. This has led to my decision of hosting my media on my own website.

I am looking for a pre-built system (by system I mean like a CMS) that can host and serve this data. The three main criteria I have, is for it to be fast to bulk upload media, fast/easy to serve media and easy to post meta-data (comments, title etc.).

I understand why FB and YouTube are slow. They convert the media to a format such as FLV or another codec. I don't want to do this, as this website will only be available to my close friends.

Is there any such pre-built system, or will I have to make my own?

**NOTE:** Using PHP thanks, my server doesn't support ASP or JavaServlets

Comment: Have you tried a faster connection? :) Seriously, FB has 700 mln users and youtube a greater number, and yet they're NOT SLOW. Uploading and downloading/streaming time depends much on network speed and latency...Are you sure your custom php only website with loads of AVI / MPEG / WHATEVER would be significally _faster_ than those highly-optimized million-dollars-driven websites?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I have thought of that. I guess my internet is rather slow (Australia, only just getting fibre optics lol) however that isn't one of my main reasons. I also want to be able to bulk upload data, which FB doesn't support. Also my website is only being used by a small group of friends (30 ppl approx) so I'm not worried about speed.

Comment: If you're the only one to provide content, just create a nice front-end and upload everthing through FTP, will surely be faster and save you a lot of code problems when dealing with uploads/limits/file checks and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend drupal. There are many like it but I'd say that this is one of the best ones.

There are thousands of modules you can add and a lot for media.

Comment: Drupal is an all-purpose CMS; it surely can do this but its not _dedicated_ , which seems to be what OP's asking. Next guy that passes here will surely reccomend Wordpress because there are thousands plugins that can do this. And the next will praise Joomla! for the big community and the huge number of extensions that allow media upload. I mean, these are all ADD-ONS to an existing multipurpose CMS which is born to do other things. If you want just ONE thing you're on the wrong track, although you can twist your path and get to destination nonetheless

Comment: Wordpress is another excellent choice but Joomla, not quite the beast... Also he says "like a CMS" so I think you're wrong when stating that he's after a dedicated system. Also if I were to present something to friends I'd also want the features of a CMS to make a nice site the way I want it.

Comment: Sorry by like a CMS, I was referring to the pre-built state of the code, not (many of) the features offered by a CMS.